# Restler SerializedFile is not working

Tags: php, api, rest, restler

I've installed Restler with success.  Everything is working ok except the `SerializedFile.php`.
I've made sure that it is un-commented, folder and files have correct permissions and it is still not working.

when i open the page and navigate to `/Authors` (in the _007_crud example), I get an empty page and no `data_serialize.php` file get created.

when i try the `mysql` or the `sqlite` versions, everything is working good.

any ideas why does the `serializedFile.php` not work?

regards

Answer (score 0):

It basically creates `data_serialized.php` in the same folder as `SerializedFile.php` all you need to make sure is, that `DB` folder is writable with necessary file permissions.